# Permissions question in OS X Lion

Tags: macos, permissions, osx-lion

Previously under 10.4, 10.5 and 10.6 I stored authorization details into a file in the Preferences folder in the main Library folder on the installing machine.

With the introduction of Lion the permissions on the Preferences folder have changed. I'm currently downloading Lion to sort this out myself but in the meantime (eager customers) does anyone have a recommendation of where to store such data safely on Lion. Application Support?

Thanks,
Stephen

Comment: Writing to /Library/Preferences would have failed under 10.6 as well for non-administrator users. If you want to write there, you need to authenticate and get increased permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

~/Library/Application Support/CompanyName/

Comment: This is a good alternative if you have only one user, or don't want to share the data with other users. In my case, I'm in trouble because I use to use both ~/Library/Application Support/xxxx and /Library/Application Support/xxxx to store data that could be used by every user. =(

Answer (score 1):

The [Keychain](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/01introduction/introduction.html) would be your best bet.

Comment: I hadn't thought about the Keychain. By authorization details I basically mean serial number. This may make life easier for users who migrate from 1 computer to another.

Answer (score 0):

The correct location appears to be /Users/Shared/

Comment: No, that's for shared *documents*. Don't dump random support files in there.

Comment: You're right. The correct place appears to be Application Support. Specifically the user domain version.